# Using pdfminer to locate a given position (commands to be used)

Tags: python, pdfminer

I need to use pdfminer to access text following horizontal textbox object:

`LTTextBoxHorizontal(133.58, 782.55, 174.03704, 802.68)`

I had used pdfminer to find this region but can't find the command to use this in multiple pdfs to look up this piece of text for this specific position.

Many thanks in advance

Simon

Comment: I think you can use a for loop for that. Can you provide more code as example of what yo're trying to do?

Comment: Post the code on the question

Comment: Hi William, thanks for the swift response, had tried the following for l in layout:
    if isinstance (l, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
        if pos ==133 or pos==782 or pos==174 or pos==802:
            lender=l.get_text()

        pos += 1   (had changed the positions to integers